# Read cli input without calling python operator

Tags: airflow

We want to read cli input pass to dag from UI during Dagtrigger in Dag.

I tried below code but its not working. I am passing input as `{""kpi":"ID123"}` and I want to print this ip value in my function `get_data_from_bq`:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow import models
from airflow.models import Variable
from google.cloud import bigquery
from airflow.configuration import conf

LOCATION          = Variable.get("HDM_PROJECT_LOCATION")
PROJECT_ID        = Variable.get("HDM_PROJECT_ID")
client = bigquery.Client()
kpi='{{ kpi}}'
# default arguments
default_dag_args = {
    'start_date':days_ago(0),
    'retries': 0,
    'project_id': PROJECT_ID
}

# Setting airflow environment variable, getting hdm_batch_details data and updating it
def get_data_from_bq(**kwargs):
    print("op is:")
    print(kpi)

#Dag Defination
with models.DAG(
        '00_test_sql1',
        schedule_interval=None,
        default_args=default_dag_args) as dag:
        
        v_run_sql_01 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='Run_SQL',
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=get_data_from_bq,
        location=LOCATION,
        use_legacy_sql=False)

v_run_sql_01
```

Note: I don't want to use any operator to read data passed from cli

Answer (score 0):

> Note: I don't want to use any operator to read data passed from cli

This is impossible. Dag Run is only created when there are tasks to run.

You should understand that :

- DAG + its top level code - builds DAG structure consisting of Tasks
- DAG Run -> is single instance of DAG run which contains Task Instances to be executed. Dag Run simply consists of task instancess that belong to the DAG run with the given "dag run".

The configuration that you pass is "dag_run.conf" not "dag.conf" - which meanss that it is only specified for the DagRun, which is valid only for all Task Instances that belong to it.

Only Task Instances have access to `dag_run.conf`